# Upload package to windows azure web site programmatically using C#

Tags: azure, azure-storage, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

My goal is to be able to deploy a package of ASP.NET website stored in Azure Storage as Azure Web Site programmatically (using C# ASP.NET) with just a click of a button. I know this can be done if I will deploy it as Azure Cloud Service by using Service Management API or azure powershell.

I dig into the source code of azure powershell and I see that it can only deploy from local Git and GitHub repo. Does anyone have any idea of how to do it from Azure Storage?

Note: I want to be able to manage all the Web Deploy Packages (stored in Azure Storage) online. I have an ASP.NET MVC website deployed as Azure web site and I will be using this one to automate deployments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you packaging your site in blog storage?  One way to publish to Windows Azure Web Sites is to use web deploy.  You could package your site as a web deploy package as part of your build, and then use msdeploy.exe to push your bits to the site:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106(v=ws.10).aspx

This would be no different from using web deploy to publish to an IIS Server.

It looks like someone else has used this approach with success:
http://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2013/06/01/windows-azure-web-sites-programmatic-web-deploy/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Justin but my goal is to be able to manage all the Web Deploy Packages on the web. I have an ASP.NET MVC website deployed as Azure web site and I will be using this one to automate deployments.

Comment: You should be able to run msdeploy.exe from the code in your website :) I think you would have to deploy the exe (and a few dlls) with your management site, but it probably can be done.  Seems someone has done this here:  http://forums.iis.net/t/1176318.aspx

Comment: I just tried it. It's works fine if the package is located in the local. In my case this won't work since the package is in Azure Storage. :/

Comment: Downloading the package from blob storage into your local app should work fine.  As long as you don't depend on packages on the local disk for more than the length of a request you're fine.  You would download the package, run the command, and then delete.  I believe your application directory is writable in waws by default.

Comment: I have no choice but to download the 200MB package from blob storage to local app. Such a pain I think but this is the only current solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could totally do this using the Windows Azure Management Libraries and the Storage SDK together. If I'm right in reading this, do you want a Web Site that you use to spin up new Cloud Services, and you want to deploy those services from the server side of your web site. If that's the case, you could do that using the [Compute Management Client](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute/) NuGet.